# Nearby connections works only with Wifi [IOS]

Tags: ios, google-play-services, google-nearby, ios-bluetooth, google-nearby-connections

I'm trying to implement Google's Nearby connectios library in ios but I noticed that discovery and advertising only works when the devices are connected to the same wifi network. That is, I believe that the problem is that research and publication takes place only via LAN and not via bluetooth.  I tried to implement the request for all the necessary permissions for the bluetooth but it still doesn't work. Any solutions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently an open issue on the [Nearby GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/nearby/issues/1619).

BLE support is not enabled for iOS yet, but you can manually enable the feature by setting the flag to `true`, as [described here](https://github.com/google/nearby/blob/21d2efbccd5607fb8d9fa2b4c8f5474e4d9169af/connections/implementation/flags/nearby_connections_feature_flags.h#L32).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there an indicative timeline for when the issues will be officially resolved?